# Move gridlines in WPF Charting toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

Is it somehow possible to move gridlines in WPF Charting toolkit. I have following XAML code:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="lineChart" 
                       Title="Statistik" 
                       FontSize="16"
                       PlotAreaStyle="{StaticResource PlotAreaStyle}"
                       FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                       Margin="73,10,10,80"
                       Background="White"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
   <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Title="Solgt"
                               Name="seriesSolgt"
                               DependentValuePath="Value" 
                               IndependentValuePath="Key"
                               IsSelectionEnabled="True">
      <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
         <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y"                        
                                     Title="Beløb"
                                     ShowGridLines="True" />
      </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
   </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
   <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Title="Betalt"
                               Name="seriesBetalt"
                               DependentValuePath="Value" 
                               IndependentValuePath="Key" 
                               IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
   <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Title="Skylder"
                               Name="seriesSkylder"
                               DependentValuePath="Value" 
                               IndependentValuePath="Key"
                               IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
   <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
      <chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" 
                                    Title="Dato"
                                    ShowGridLines="True"
                                    GridLineStyle="{StaticResource GridLineStyle}" />
   </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

And my chart looks like this:

[image]

I want to shift my vertical gridlines to be on the dots.

Comment: 1 extra line for every dot? or lines only for the dots? perhaps a custom scale for the axis could help you if exists or you may implement your own `CustomRangeAxis` if allowed.

Comment: 1 extra line for every dot would be nice